# Получение и потеря фокуса во время звонка

Tags: android

Есть активити, где проигрывается аудио. Подскажите как тут сделать так, чтобы когда кто-то звонит, громкость воспроизведения уменьшалась, а когда звонок завершился опять нормализовалась?

Вот код активности

```
public class Player extends AppCompatActivity implements MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener, MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener {

    private TextView txtSongText;
    private ImageView img;
    private ImageButton btnPlay;
    private ImageButton btnFavorites;
    private ImageButton btnPrev;
    private ImageButton btnNext;

    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    AudioManager am;
    NotificationManager notificationManager;
    Notification builder;
    BroadcastReceiver br;

    KidsDBHeler dbHeler;

    private boolean isPlay;

    private String title = "";
    private String text = "";
    private String filename = "";
    private String image = "";
    private String author = "";
    private String source = "";
    private int favorite;
    private int currentId = 0;
    private String MAYBE_ACTION = "MAYBE_ACTION";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_player);

        title = getIntent().getExtras().getString("title");

        dbHeler = new KidsDBHeler(this);

        am = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);

        img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);
        btnPlay = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);
        btnFavorites = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnFavorites);
        btnPrev = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnPrev);
        btnNext = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
        txtSongText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtSongText);

        String query = "SELECT * " + " FROM " + KidsContract.KidsEntry.TABLE_SONGS + " WHERE " + KidsContract.KidsEntry.COLUMN_TITLE + " = " + "\"" + title + "\"";
        navPrevNext(query);
    }

    public void onPlay(View view) {
        if (mediaPlayer == null) {
            return;
        }

        if (isPlay == true) {
            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                mediaPlayer.pause();
                btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_play);
                isPlay = false;
            }
        } else if (isPlay == false) {
            if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                mediaPlayer.start();
                btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_pause);
                isPlay = true;
            }
        }
    }

    public void onPrev(View view) {
        currentId--;

        if (currentId < 1) {
            btnPrev.setEnabled(false);
            currentId++;
        } else {
            btnPrev.setEnabled(true);
            btnNext.setEnabled(true);
            String query = "SELECT * " + " FROM " + KidsContract.KidsEntry.TABLE_SONGS + " WHERE " + KidsContract.KidsEntry._ID + " = " + currentId;
            navPrevNext(query);

            NotificationManager notifManager= (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notifManager.cancelAll();
            unregisterReceiver(br);
            createNotifycation();
        }
    }

    public void onNext(View view) {
        currentId++;

        if (currentId > dbHeler.getDBItemCount()) {
            btnNext.setEnabled(false);
            currentId--;
        } else {
            btnPrev.setEnabled(true);
            btnNext.setEnabled(true);
            String query = "SELECT * " + " FROM " + KidsContract.KidsEntry.TABLE_SONGS + " WHERE " + KidsContract.KidsEntry._ID + " = " + currentId;
            navPrevNext(query);

            NotificationManager notifManager= (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notifManager.cancelAll();
            unregisterReceiver(br);
            createNotifycation();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                currentId++;

                if (currentId > dbHeler.getDBItemCount()) {
                    btnNext.setEnabled(false);
                    currentId--;
                    System.out.println(currentId);
                } else {
                    btnPrev.setEnabled(true);
                    btnNext.setEnabled(true);
                    String query = "SELECT * " + " FROM " + KidsContract.KidsEntry.TABLE_SONGS + " WHERE " + KidsContract.KidsEntry._ID + " = " + currentId;
                    navPrevNext(query);
                    createNotifycation();
                }
            }
        });

        createNotifycation();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mp.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        NotificationManager notifManager= (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notifManager.cancelAll();
        super.onDestroy();
        releaseMP();
        unregisterReceiver(br);
    }

    private void releaseMP() {
        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
            try {
                mediaPlayer.release();
                mediaPlayer = null;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    //Метод для выгрузки из БД и воспроизведения аудио
    public void navPrevNext(String query) {
        Cursor cursor = dbHeler.database.rawQuery(query, null);
        try {
            if (cursor.getCount() != 0) {
                while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                    title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KidsContract.KidsEntry.COLUMN_TITLE));
                    text = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KidsContract.KidsEntry.COLUMN_TEXT));
                    filename = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KidsContract.KidsEntry.COLUMN_FILENAME));
                    image = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KidsContract.KidsEntry.COLUMN_IMAGE));
                    favorite = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(KidsContract.KidsEntry.COLUMN_FAVORITE));
                    currentId = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(KidsContract.KidsEntry._ID));
                    author = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KidsContract.KidsEntry.COLUMN_AUTHOR));
                    source = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KidsContract.KidsEntry.COLUMN_SOURCE));

                    if (favorite == 1) {
                        btnFavorites.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_star_yellow);
                    } else if (favorite == 0){
                        btnFavorites.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_star_outline_black);
                    }

                    actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
                    SpannableString s = new SpannableString(title);
                    s.setSpan(new TypefaceSpan(this, "Dolores.otf"), 0, s.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                    actionBar.setTitle(s);

                    if (source == null || source.isEmpty()) {
                        txtSongText.setText(title);
                    } else {
                        txtSongText.setText(title + " - " + source);
                    }
                    txtSongText.append("\n");
                    txtSongText.append(author);
                    txtSongText.append("\n\n");
                    txtSongText.append(text.replace("\\n", "\n"));

                    try {
                        InputStream ims = getAssets().open("img/" + image + ".jpg");
                        Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(ims, null);
                        img.setImageDrawable(d);
                    } catch(IOException ex) {
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
        } finally {
            cursor.close();
        }

        releaseMP();
        try {
            AssetFileDescriptor afd = getAssets().openFd("music/" + filename + ".mp3");
            mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(),afd.getStartOffset(),afd.getLength());
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
            mediaPlayer.start();
            isPlay = true;
            btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_pause);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (mediaPlayer == null) {
            return;
        }
    }

    public void createNotifycation() {
        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Player.class);
        intent.putExtra("title", title);
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
        Intent closeIntent = new Intent();
        closeIntent.setAction(MAYBE_ACTION);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 12345, closeIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16) {
            builder = new Notification.Builder(this)
                    .setTicker(title)
                    .setContentTitle("Играет: " + title)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).setContentIntent(pIntent)
                    .addAction(R.drawable.icon_stop, "Стоп", pendingIntent)
                    .build();

            builder.flags = builder.flags | Notification.FLAG_INSISTENT | Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;

            notificationManager.notify(0, builder);
        } else {

        }

        br = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                finish();
            }
        };
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(MAYBE_ACTION);
        registerReceiver(br, intentFilter);
    }

}
```

Читал про получение и потерю фокуса, но не разобрался как работать с этим.

Answer (score 1):

Если вам нужно уменьшать звук во время звонка, то вам нужно не потерю фокуса обрабатывать, а сообщения от [TelephonyManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html):

```
PhoneStateListener phoneStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
        ....
    }
};
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
int events = PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE;
tm.listen(phoneStateListener, events);
```

За подробностями [сюда](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html#onCallStateChanged(int,%20java.lang.String)).